# List streams of a particular DynamoDB table using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-dynamodb-streams

How can I list all the streams associated with one dynamo db table using CLI (terminal aws command)? Even listing all the streams didn't work for me:

```
aws dynamodb list-streams
```

Answer (score 1):

To list the DynamoDb streams for a table, use this command

```
aws dynamodbstreams list-streams --table-name
```